# Columns with corresponding content

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have some structured content in HTML – for example text in paragraphs grouped into some sections. And let's say I have another instance of the same structure and I want to display both contents as two columns side by side using HTML and CSS. How to do that? The point is that I want that corresponding elements (paragraphs, sections) inside the columns are aligned so they start at the same height.

Examples of such structures may be a bilingual page, or a source code together with numbers of lines or with some side comments to individual lines.

The only idea I have is to use a table, but I'm not sure it is the best solution. I want to be able to select the content as if the column was an ordinary web page, but selecting in a table works in a way that cells in a row are selected first.

An example follows. Recall that I want the corresponding elements to start at the same height.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Corresponding columns</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .main {
                margin: auto;
                width: 500px;
            }
            .column {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
            }
            .corresponding {
                background-color: #FFFF99;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Section</h1>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <h2 class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
                <p>Some other text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Section</h1>
                <p>The text translated to another language, which may be longer.</p>
                <h2 class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
                <p>Some other text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: @DestinationDesigns As I said I don't know how to implement the desired feature. Only by using tables, but then the selection is broken. My problem is not to implement a typical two-column layout – the web is full of tutorials about those. I desire the key feature of correspondence between the columns.

Comment: I think that you need to separate each elements that you need to put in parallel. So if you have 2 paragraphs and you need to translate it, and each paragraph needs to be parallel, you need to divide each paragraph, identify it and then read the position X-Y of each left paragraph and apply its position to right paragraph. This is a valid behaviour for you?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Reading and changing the positions would mean to use javascript. Is there really no standard declarative solution for this situation? Note that the situation also includes line numbers of a source code, but that is typically done by simply assuming that the lines and the line numbers elements have the same height so it works. But what if a line in a source code is too long so it is wrapped? Is there really no easy solution for such situation?

Comment: It's difficult because you don't know what width have each line. I see this problem solved only with javascript. Sorry.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Do you mean the height of each line? I know but there are many CSS constructs to align elements without knowing their absolute positions. I wanted to know if there is a technique to solve also this problem.

Comment: Yes, if you make an structure based on rows, as the answer of @LGSon said. But you need js anyway because you need to wrap each line in a row / col set, and it's very possible that you extract the data of a database without wrapping.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Doesn't setting `width: 50%;` solve the width problem from columns?

Comment: Yes , but not the height. however, I didn't talk about this, I am talking about wrap the lines that I think is the most important thing to solve. Your wish is achieve that lines are parallel in horizontal mode, so you need to know the height of the biggest line to apply to the smallest line.

Answer (score 8):

If you want each section/subsection to start at the same height I would suggest to do like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Section</h1>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Section</h1>
            <p>The text translated to another language, which may be longer.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
            <p>Some other text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
            <p>This text might also be longer so you need to push the next section's as well to start at the same height</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same (almost) as a table but with div's.

I'm no "flex-box" expert so that might be a way, though with less broad browser support.

If you can't/don't want to use the "row" elements (and no/can't/don't want flex option) you will need a javascript snippet that iterate through your elements and compute margins to be set.

**UPDATE**

Check these 2 links, they will help you set this up as you like using flex:
- https://chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/using-flexbox-today/#card-layout
- http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/PwPwWd/

A future proof way without using javascript.

**UPDATE 2**

And this one has some really cool grid solutions:
- https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: Yes, it's like a table, but it shares the problem with table that is messes up selection. I want to be able to make selects in individual columns as if there was just one column.

Comment: When you say "make selections", do you mean mark/select the text in a sub and its subsection with a mouse? ... or to have them react as one on a "css hover" rule?

Comment: LGSon: Yes. For example in the „line numbers of a source code example“ I want to be able to select the source code by mouse a be able to extract it with correct whitespace.

Comment: Updated my answer, you will find a "non javascript" way how to do on those 2 pages I linked to.

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising.

Comment: I have looked at the links and learnt something about flex, but I'm still not sure how to use it. Note that for example in the first link, the elements are aligned just because there is only one item of non-fixed size in a column. I have put together a solution, but it has still some drawbacks – see my selfanswer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I dont know what exactly You want... I thing that You might want two sections side-by-side, where You can place anything... Thats what I found:

make two div's `<div id="first">` and `<div id="second">`

and place what You want in them. Now css:

```
#first {float:left;width:50%;}

#second {float:right;width:50%;}
```

Make sure You have `body {padding:0; margin:0;}`

Comment: The point is that those divs contain some content that is in correspondence, e.g. there is a paragraph in the left column and there is a corresponding paragraph in the second column. And I want these paragraphs to be aligned, i.e. the both start at the same height. And it is not just the paragraphs, it is the whole HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are searching for an HTML-structure which shows two items next to each other. Each of the properties of this item (i.e. the subsections) should have the same height. And, when the user selects the text, then the whole row (i.e. the same property from both items) should be selected.

I have the feeling that in order for the user to be able to select content the way you want, the structure needs to be correct, as I believe that the browser selects content according to the structure (not sure, this is always true though).

The question is, if you are free to use any HTML-structure you like?

When I try below example, it works for me. The solution is to use a list (`ul` with `li`) per "property" (row), making the `li`s  display as `inline-block`. That way, they don't break and, as they are `block` elements, they always have the same height per "line". With `vertical-align: top;` all content starts at the beginning of the element.

I adjusted the content so we definitely have different line heights and wrapping, just to be sure it works.

Styling:

```
<style>
    ul {
        list-style: none;   
    }

    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2<br/>(with new line)</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>The text translated to another language, which may be longer.<br /><br />
    The text translated to another language, which may be longer. 
    The text translated to another language, which may be longer. 
    The text translated to another language, which may be longer. 
    The text translated to another language, which may be longer. 
    The text translated to another language, which may be longer. </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>The text translated to another language, which may be longer. 
        The text translated to another language, which may be longer.</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want the selection to work the other way – to be able to select the whole column. That's the core of the problem. If we change the structure to a big column containing rows containing the corresponding elements, then we have the alignment but we lose the selection. If we have two big columns containg whole corresponding structures, then we have the selection but we cannot align the corresponding elements horizontally.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry misunderstood the question in that case.. I was going for the rows, not the columns. I'm not aware of any way to achieve this, except with JavaScript and setting the height of the smaller element to the height of it's larger "partner"-element. According to the other answers, there might be a solution though. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Thank to LGSon, I have learnt about flex. I tried to put together a solution. The following code somehow works, but there are some issues:

1. One has to add `order` attribute to all elements.

   For some reason flex doesn't overlap margins like it is done in standard situation so all the vertical spaces are bigger.

   It would be know hard to e.g. add a border around whole column.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Corresponding columns</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                margin: auto;
                width: 500px;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            .container > * {
                flex: 0 0 50%;
            }
            .corresponding {
                background-color: #FFFF99;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="order: 1">Section</h1>
            <p style="order: 2">Some text</p>
            <h2 style="order: 3" class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
            <p style="order: 4">Some other text</p>

            <h1 style="order: 1">Section</h1>
            <p style="order: 2">The text translated to another language, which may be longer.</p>
            <h2 style="order: 3" class="corresponding">Subsection</h2>
            <p style="order: 4">Some other text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As i wrote, when you really need two "individual" columns where an item in one can be paired with an item in the other, javascript will be needed to achieve that, and it can be done with not to much fuss. For p.3 you can do that easily using the psuedo classes :after/:before on the container. Set them as absolute, a border, width 50%, height 100%, top 0 and one left 0 and the other left 50% ... zindex on :after lower than column items

Comment: You don't need to add the inline `style="order: n"`, you can do it with css: 
`.container h1 { order: 1 }
.container h2 { order: 3 }
.container p:nth-of-type(1n) { order: 2 }
.container p:nth-of-type(2n) { order: 4 }`

Comment: @LGSon: But that style would work just for my particular content, right?

Comment: It works for h1, h2 and p elements which are children of the .container element as in your answer

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, "avoid inline style as much as you can" and use css and classes to style your html. Soooo much easier to maintain when/if you want to do changes.

Comment: @LGSon: I understand it is generally good idea to avoid inline style, but this is a special case. A functionally equivalent code here would be to use `class=order-n` and then to have style `order-n { order: n}`, which doesn't add any benefit. Of course I will polish the code as soon as I find a proof of concept that is good enough.

Comment: May I suggest to read the article at http://blog.millermedeiros.com/pragmatic-css-using-js-and-inline-styles/. It will give you some hints when and why to use or not use inline styles, but the biggest benefit is to have code and style separated and thats why `class=order-n` beats the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Use css `column-count` CSS property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

**Update**

After re-reading the question, I think if you want both columns to start at the same height, you can use min-height on both columns, but be aware that the content will later push the height as it grows.

To maintain the height even with content, put a fixed height then have apply `overflow-y:auto;` or `overflow-y:scroll`. That way both boxes will have the same height, and can be scrollable in case content grows

Comment: How does it relate to my question?

Comment: You wanted to split the content into columns, no?

Comment: No, I have two instances of the same HTML sctructure and I want to display them in two columns. The point is that I want the corresponding elements to start at the same height.

Comment: @user87690 I've updated my answer above, hope that helps

Comment: I don't only want the whole columns to have the same height but also all the pairs of corresponding elements contained in that colunms. For example you can renred the example in the question. I'm looking for a way make the correspoinding h2s to be vertically aligned, so they are displayed side by side.

Comment: I see, then simply apply `width:50%; float:left;` to the `columns` class

Comment: Did you look at the example? It's already there. But the point is that I want the corresponding items in the columns to start at the same height. I really don't know if I explain it so poorly or that people just think it's yet another newbie question about two-column layout, so they easily miss the point of the question.